# Linking Jquery with HTML

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I can't understand what is wrong with this. It may be a linking problem, but i can't tell wich one. index.html, script.js and jquery's library files are in my desktop. This is the code:

This is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>asdasd</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Jquery external sheet:

```
$(document).ready((function) {
("h1").click((function) {
    (this).hide();
});
});
```

There's no CSS sheet, because I made it simple, so I could be sure it's not wrong, but maybe it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"
```

Protocol-less URLs do not work through the `file:///` scheme.

Put an `http://` in place of `//` and it should work. However, using a localhost server is a better way around in the long term. `=]`

With a localhost server you can run your page through `http://` easily so it gets you through that error and many other file permission issues that you may run into in the future. Here are a few easy to install servers: [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/), [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/)

---

Also `(function)` should be `function()` and you're missing a `$`:

```
$(document).ready((function) {
    ("h1").click((function) {
```

Should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").click(function() {
```

Try running your code through [JSHint](http://jshint.com/), it will find those basic syntax errors for you.

Comment: Thank you SO much. I've always had this problem, but now you've saved me! Thanks for all the information.

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

You need to add `http:` to your `script`'s `src` attribute

You should pull this from your own server though. As Crockford says:

> Use your own copy. It is extremely unwise to load code from servers you do not control.

Also the code block is a little wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("h1").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the $ object

```
$(this).hide();
```